# Hadoop Hive - percentile_approx not able to use dynamic argument

Tags: hadoop, dynamic, hive, percentile

This query works fine:

```
select percentile_approx(values, 0.75)
from t1 
inner join t2 on (t1.id = t2.id) and t1.id = 123;
```

But this query throws an error:

```
select percentile_approx(values, cast(t2.percent as double ))
from t1 
inner join t2 on (t1.id = t2.id) and t1.id = 123;
```

> FAILED: UDFArgumentTypeException The second argument must be a constant, but double was passed instead.

How can I make the second argument (percentile) dynamic (coming from a different table)?

**Note**:  There will be greater than 1000 calculations and will also involve doing a `group by`; so running 1 by 1 is not an option -- in that case, it would be 1,000 different Hive queries which would run forever.